# Using IconUri and IconBackGroundColor for a Windows toast message

Tags: c++, windows, shell, com, toast

I have a standard C++ program using COM. The [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-other-apps) describes how to register a normal application to retrieve a local toast notification.

This works for me, but I wonder about the parameters in the registry described.

Using `IconBackgroundColor` has no influence on the appearance in the Windows Information Center.
A transparent PNG is always shown on the current dark grey background. The given syntax should be hex chars Alpha followed by RGB. So the contents `00FFFFFF` should show a solid white background.

How to use `IconBackgroundColor` correct?

Also the `IconUri` seams to work only with PNG,BMP. I know from other locations in the registry that I can use embedded resources. Bot no ICO files.

Is this to use `IconUri` with an Icon or embedded resource ?

If I create a LNK file and not using the registry with my `Application User Model ID` the icon is taken from the EXE... but that is not what I want.

I can see no documentation here.

Edit: Using FFFFFFFF as a back ground color doesn't has an effect either.

Comment: Difficult to find complete documentation... You can override everything with toast content XML : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=xml#app-logo-override note they don't say much about image format, only source (http, etc.) ...

Comment: No. I am not talking about the toast image. It is the image that the Windows Info Center shows for my application. You see a Dropbox, or Outlook Icon here.

Comment: Have you clicked on the link?

Comment: Yes I did. But I mean the "title" and the "icon" above the toast in the Windows Information center. Not the Icon in the toast. All Information ist grouped by the application causing the action. Above a DropBox toast I see the Dropbox Icon and the Title "Dropbox". In my case I have my toast with the desired icon, above the name I gave and defined and the icon defined in IconUri.

Comment: AARRGGBB means alpha should not be 00, try FF.

Comment: Using FFFFFFFF doesn't have an effect either.